# Java: system.out.println concatenating something within a string (really easy question)

Tags: java, syntax, println

I want my output to be Candy[1].
counterInt = 1

But my compiler isn't taking this code:

```
   System.out.println("Candy["+counterInt"]");
```

What can I do to have this variable appear within the string Candy[]?

Candy[] is not an array, it's a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must put a `+` after `counterInt`:

```
System.out.println("Candy["+counterInt+"]");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.println("Candy["+counterInt+"].counterInt="+counterInt);
```

Answer (score 1):

you should have  System.out.println("Candy[" + counterInt + "].counterInt = " + counterInt); to get Candy[1]. counterInt = 1;

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a + after CounterInt.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Candy["+counterInt+"]");
```